# Markdown continue numbering after headings

Tags: github, markdown

I need to continue the numbering after heading 2 as it appears here in stackoverflow. But in Github this numbering re-starts.

#### heading 1

1. item 1

#### heading 2

2. item 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR

You can't do this in GitHub's flavor of Markdown.

### Use Markdown Flavors with List Extensions

[GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/) doesn't support list continuation. Continuations require extensions to [standard Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) such as [Pandoc's example lists](http://pandoc.org/README.html#numbered-example-lists).

Other Markdown flavors may support variations of global numbering, too. However, what you want is not currently possible on GitHub.

Comment: that's sad, what's TL;DR? and how do I use other flavours or markdown in github? just changing extension would do?

Comment: @User, you can't use other types of Markdown with GitHub. (It actually [uses two slightly different versions depending on where on GitHub the Markdown is being used](https://developer.github.com/v3/markdown/), but there is no way to change GitHub's Markdown rendering behaviour.)

Comment: @User TL;DR: "Too Long; Don't Read"